# Python script has to be run twice to execute

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a python script to gather and analyze data from a `.csv` file and then plot it using the `matplotlib.pyplot` module. I'm using `numpy.genfromtext()` to gather the data.

The first time I run the file, nothing happens. I get the console message:

```
>>> runfile('C:/my_filepath/thing.py')
```

and nothing more. If I run the file again, then it executes, prints the stuff, the plot comes up etc:

```
runfile('C:/my_filepath/thing.py')
~the stuff it's supposed to print~
```

More info: This problem only occurs on my laptop computer, which leads me to believe it has something to do with my matplotlib installation (mysterious to me because I installed an identical Anaconda package on my desktop and there is no issue). On the laptop the plot window is separate, and on the desktop the plot displays in the console. Maybe that's relevant.

Has anyone had this issue?

edit2: This only happens if I try to run the program multiple times in the same console. If I run the script in a fresh console it works fine, then you have to run it twice for every execution. If I close the matplotlib window, kill the console, and open a new one, I can execute it fine every time.

edit: here is a working example which exhibits the odd behavior. don't make fun of my code - I learned python over a weekend

```
import re
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt as gft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getnames(Pattern):
    #construct the list of files in the directory
    CSVList = []
    for FileName in os.listdir():
        if re.compile(Pattern).search(FileName):
            CSVList.append(FileName)

    print(len(CSVList), 'files found.')


    #sort the list by the integer values of the last 4 digits of the    filename
    CSVList.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('.')[0][-4:]))


    return CSVList

def xy_extract(Data):
    x = np.array([row[0] for row in Data])
    y = np.array([row[1] for row in Data])

    return x, y

CSVList = getnames('(?i)\.csv$')
print(CSVList)

#plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.xlim(799,3999)

for Filename in CSVList:
    Data = gft(Filename, delimiter=',',skip_header=2)
    x, y = xy_extract(Data)

    plt.plot(x, y,label=Filename)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you check if a python process is running after the first execution that doesn't seem to output data?

Comment: can you share your code or a MWE (minimum working example)?

Comment: this may also be an issue with the configuration of your editor... try it from cmd: `C:/my_filepath>python thing.py`

Comment: I can indeed. I will add it to my post.

Comment: another note that is specific to using editors vs using cmd/terminal is interactive mode with matplotlib. depending on the configuration having a graph open may block the current process from terminating, or it may run in a separate thread and permit live updates (since you're using the global context with plt) see [This](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) for official details

Comment: what happens if you put `plt.ion()` after your imports?

Comment: Works fine for me in Python 2.7 if I (a) add `import os` to the top, and (b) explicitly supply the argument `'.'` in `os.listdir('.')`  (I realize this is Python 3 code but I don't have a matplotlib-included Python 3 distro easily available).  Matplotlib's "interactive mode" is probably the key to your problem, as Aaron pointed out.